# Android SQlite table in a separate module

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-module

I am developing a new module in an existing android project. The existing project is already having a database with some tables. In the new module I need a new table called **Audio**. In future I may use this module in some other apps(which would be already having database) too. 
What is the better approach to get a table **Audio**?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate class and implement your queries and operations there.

```
public static final String newTabQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MY_TABLE
        + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT)";
```

You can create generic methods for different database operations

```
 public void insertData(SQLiteOpenHelper helper, Data queryValues) {

        SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("id", queryValues.getId());
        values.put("name", queryValues.getName());

        database.insert(DATA_TRACKING_TABLE, null, values);
        database.close();
    }
```